# Changing Brightness

Tags: brightness, ubuntu-16.04, viewport

On entering workspace switcher, I have a grid of 3 x 3.

The active workspace has a brightness of 100% and the inactive workspaces have a brightness of 40%.

In ccsm under Desktop --> Expo --> Appearance --> Inactive Viewports I can only change the brightness of the inactive viewports.

**How can I *lower* the brightness of the active workspace?**

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the perceived brightness of the active viewport by simply increasing the brightness of the inactive viewports